# How can I use stage.scaleMode property in AS3 in class?

Tags: class, actionscript-3, stage

I only use classes. There is the "main" class of my app.

[Code printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cQS6.png)

Answer (score 1):

That's right, you just forgot to import the `StageScaleMode` class:

```
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
```

Comment: Thanks mate! It works. Still, the code has to be written on frame, not in class ;).

Comment: @danutpopa Nope, that's not true. This works in a class.

Comment: It won't work in a constructor as `stage` will be null. Try adding an `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` event listener and setting the stage scale mode in the handler.